# 'Proof' that $f''(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, fake-proofs

Consider the following:

$$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}$$
Now using L'Hopital's rule (as this is a case of an inderterminate) we have
$$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{hx}$$
But this is
$$\frac{1}{x}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
which is $\frac{1}{x}f'(x)$.

So it would seem that
$$f''(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{x}$$ which is quite obviously false. Where is my error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: L'Hopital applies to the variable of which you are taking the limit, that is $h$, not $x$.

Comment: @Brainstorming I see what you mean now, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'Hôpital's rule actually implies$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{hx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f^\prime(x+h)}{x},$$not$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{hx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f^\prime(x+h)-f^\prime(x)}{h}.$$As @Brainstorming notes, your derivative was with respect to the wrong variable.

Comment: Ah, and the $f(x)$ disappears because we can really treat it as a constant?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Got it in one.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer!